# org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Error while invoking ESAPI.encoder()

Tags: java, servlets, esapi

I am getting the following error while executing the following code. It was working earlier now suddenly started throwing this exception.

```html
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.owasp.esapi.Encoder;
import org.owasp.esapi.codecs.Codec;
import org.owasp.esapi.codecs.OracleCodec;
public List<SearchUserBean> getSearchUserResult(SearchUserBean searchUserBean){
Codec ORACLE_CODEC = new OracleCodec();
String WHERE="WHERE be.EMPLOYER_ID   =comp.business_asso ";
        if (searchUserBean.getEmailAddress()!=null && !(searchUserBean.getEmailAddress().isEmpty())) {
            WHERE +="AND upper(be.EMAIL_ID) LIKE '" +ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( ORACLE_CODEC, searchUserBean.getEmailAddress().replace("*", "%").toUpperCase().trim()) +"' ";
        }   
return null;    
}
```

Error Received.

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:99)
at com.beacon.search.dao.impl.SearchUserDaoImpl.getSearchUserResult(SearchUserDaoImpl.java:73)
at com.beacon.search.services.impl.SearchUserServiceImpl.getSearchUserResult(SearchUserServiceImpl.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy294.getSearchUserResult(Unknown Source)
at com.beacon.search.controller.SearchUserController.getSearchUserResult(SearchUserController.java:133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.
```

Comment: Firstly, I hope that ESAPI code is temporary because if it's not it's time to rewrite using a `PreparedStatement.`  ESAPI's not as good as your Oracle Provider's escaping utils.  

I would start by rewriting your code here so each operation has its own line.  Check your logs for errors on ESAPI initialization.  This doesn't sound at all like a problem with ESAPI but in how it's being injected into your environment.

Comment: We  haven't done any code changes, and this is what we are getting from event logs, also we have done one os patching will that cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Vidyuth - I have a few questions.

1. What version of ESAPI were you using when it last worked and what version are you using now?
2. In your ESAPI.properties file, what do you have the property "ESAPI.Logger" set to?

One reason I ask is is because in ESAPI 2.2.1.0 release, some of the logging was restructured, so if you are coming from earlier versions and didn't update ESAPI.Logger, things will break. Here's part of the release notes from ESAPI 2.2.1.0:

```
    *** IMPORTANT WORKAROUND for 2.2.1.0 ESAPI Logging ***

Lastly, if you try to use the new ESAPI 2.2.1.0 logging, you will notice that you need to change ESAPI.Logger and also possibly provide some other logging properties as well. This is because the logger packages were reorganized to improve maintainability, but we failed to mention it. To use ESAPI logging in ESAPI 2.2.1.0 (and later), you MUST set the ESAPI.Logger property to one of:

    org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory     - To use the new default, java.util.logging (JUL)
    org.owasp.esapi.logging.log4j.Log4JLogFactory   - To use the end-of-life Log4J 1.x logger
    org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory   - To use the new (to release 2.2.0.0) SLF4J logger
```

Comment: We use esapi-2.0.1 version, Yes we have logger set too ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory. We have done one OS patch will that affect our code.

Comment: Seriously? 2.0.1? The release that came out in July 2011? Or was that '2.0.1' a typo? I'm hoping so. ESAPI 2.2.3.0 was just released this past week and if you can reproduce your problem with it and reset ESAPI.Logger to the correct new value, we then I would encourage you to write a small JUnit test to reproduce it and create a GitHub issue. But 2.0.1 likely puts you at risk because of all the outdated dependencies so I encourage you to upgrade ASAP.

Comment: It works after the restart, whenever we install a war it required a restart otherwise it throws that above error, I didn't understand the root cause.

Comment: Some JavaEE application servers "explode" war files and I've seen that cause caching issues when / if you try to hot deploy things. Usually works okay for a single JSP, but for anything else, the IBM Global Services operations staff (at my former job) would usually restart the application server. Not sure if that's your problem, but I don't think this is ESAPI specific. However, if you can provide steps to reproduce it w/ the latest ESAPI version, please file a GitHub issue for it.